# Tensorflow Image Placeholder

Tags: tensorflow, ocr

I'm writing a script in python to use tensorflow detection but I'm facing troubles with this line of code

```
images_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[905, 1053])
```

the results is

```
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 1053 and 905 for 'MatMul' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [905,1053], [905,1053].
```

does that mean the height and width should be the same? or its something else?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It would help to see the `matmul` code, because I think you need to transpose of one of your matrices for the `matmul` operation to work.

That is, you need to make sure the rows of one matrix equals the columns of the other. You can read more about this [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/precalculus/precalc-matrices/properties-of-matrix-multiplication/a/matrix-multiplication-dimensions).

Comment: reasonable enough, but the problem i don't have control over the matrix (at least that's what i know) i don't know what are the exact parameters to the placeholder, actually if you could guide me to a link that makes OCR detection for the tenserflow (a simple detection with premade model and ready data) it would be great